can't update ionic cordova from 10 to 13 - no such file gradle/aar-metadata.properties
I'm trying to update my Ionic 4 app with Cordova 10 to use Cordova 13.
So I try this commands:
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
ionic cordova build android

And then get this error
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > /Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/35f63e7f36647f7d0d810941392795dd/transformed/jetified-firebase-inappmessaging-display-20.3.2/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties (No such file or directory)

Am I missing something?
